# Atualizar componente/object Angular 6

Tags: input, angular-6, component, objetos

Tenho 3 componentes que trocam um object entre si, como faço para quando atualizar um os outros também atualizar sozinho?

Exemplo: tenho os componentes 1, 2 e 3, o 1 chama o 2 passando um object e o 2 chama o 3 passando o mesmo object, tudo isso na criação dos componentes.
Tenho que atualizar o componente 3 quando o object no componente 1 sofrer alteração.

Comment: Você tem que notificar o evento pai, e assim por diante que um evento ocorreu no componente filho. Você precisa dessa diretiva: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter. Faz uma demo aqui:https://stackblitz.com/ que saberemos melhor o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você deve utilizar o @Input, passando do pai para o filho o valor que você quer.

Neste exemplo que você deu, as propriedades dos component 2 e 3 devem ter a anotação @Input, para os pais 'inputarem' o valor nos filhos. Component inputa no 2, o 2 inputa no 3, por isso só o 2 e 3 precisam o @Input. E assim por diante.

Para enviar valor dos filhos para os pais, você deve utilizar o @Output.

O detalhamento de como utilizar o @Input e @Output no site do Angular:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Fiz um exemplo para você ver funcionando:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pufge7